# Where is the "document.getElementById()" function stored?

Tags: html, dom

I was wondering where is that function stored?

I am asking because I tried looking it up inside the console.dir(document), and couldn't find any of the methods there?

I am very curious about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The method is exposed as part of the `DocumentPrototype` object, accessible under `window.Document.prototype`:

The `window.document` instance only inherits it from the `Document` class.

```js
console.log( Document.prototype.getElementById );

Document.prototype.getElementById = (val) => 'gotcha ' + val;
console.log( document.getElementById( 'foo' ) );
```

Now, the native function being a native function, browsers don't give us access to it, and certainly, it's not even a JS function.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on native code (probably in C++) that is part of the browser. You could search for getElementById in the source code of a web browser to look at it.

JavaScript is an interpreted language; every web browser has a JavaScript interpreter. When you write JavaScript yourself, you can define methods on objects. However, what you can't do from JavaScript is write native methods; these have to be provided as part of the browser. If you try to print the source of these functions from JavaScript with toSource, you see a note indicating that these functions are in fact native.

```js
console.log((function(){}).toSource());
console.log(alert.toSource());
```

The point of native code is that it can access things which are deliberately inaccessible to JS code. For example, events can be scheduled with `window.setTimeout` despite there being absolutely no way to implement `setTimeout` in plain JS. Browsers have huge codebases, none of which I'm familiar with, so it's difficult to express in a short answer exactly they work. However, to give you a taste of their workings, [Chromium's element.cc](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/d99d67668633c97b87bd605f715f4a3afc5fa18a/third_party/blink/renderer/core/dom/element.cc) contains implementations for familiar methods like `setAttribute` and [in container_node.cc](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/5b81f8730e3f6c960fc7ebb870c5a155c30b1609/third_party/blink/renderer/core/dom/container_node.cc#L1565) there is an implementation of `getElementById`.

Comment: So the document methods are stored in the browser code? Could you please please elaborate a little more? Thanks 